# Is there some way to write scripts for Winamp?

Tags: winamp

I like to write some scripts for Winamp.  How might I do this?

Comment: You can use [ActiveWinamp](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/activewinamp/143299).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [gen_scripting plugin](http://www.pretentiousname.com/gen_scripting/index.html) which uses JSpript or VB which might be of use to you.

And a few words to the wise: Just add the plugin to the winamp plugins directory and remember to register it with regsvr32 from the command prompt. Scripting only works with Winamp running :)